# Howto retrieve data from several observables in angular

Tags: angular, observable, subscription, subscribe

I am trying to put in place in angular a call to several http service.
I need to retrieve 4 datasource from the http service.

I am using in my component a call to a service likes this.

app.component.ts

```
entitieSearchActifsDataSource: IEntitiesQuickSearchActifs[] = [];
entitieSearchResponsablesDataSource: IEntitiesQuickSearchResponsables[] = [];
entitieSearchMachinesDataSource: IEntitiesQuickSearchMachines[] = [];
entitieSearchApplicatifsDataSource: IEntitiesQuickSearchApplicatifs[] = [];

constructor(private entiteSearchService:EntiteSearchService)



.....

search(){
        this.subscriptionQuickSearch$ =
        this.entiteSearchService.getQuickSearch(this.searchValue,this.stc_Ids,+!this.switchValue)
        .subscribe(
          (sucess) => {
                      this.entitieSearchActifsDataSource = this.entiteSearchService.entitieSearchActifsDataSource;
                      this.entitieSearchResponsablesDataSource = this.entiteSearchService.entitieSearchResponsablesDataSource;
                      this.entitieSearchMachinesDataSource = this.entiteSearchService.entitieSearchMachinesDataSource;
                      this.entitieSearchApplicatifsDataSource = this.entiteSearchService.entitieSearchApplicatifsDataSource;
                      },
          (error) =>  {
                      console.log(error)
                      });
  }
```

In my service EntiteSearchService.ts

```
  public getQuickSearch(query:string, Lst_stc: string, with_orphan: number): Observable<boolean>{
    this.initialState();

    this.subscriptionQuickSearchActifs$ = this.getQuickSearchData<IEntitiesQuickSearchActifs>(Quicksearch.actif, query, Lst_stc, with_orphan)
    .subscribe(
      (entitiesSearch)=>{
                          this.entitieSearchActifsDataSource = entitiesSearch;
                          return true;

                        },
      (error)=>{
                this.entitieSearchActifsDataSource = [];
                return false;
        });

        this.subscriptionQuickSearchResponsables$ = ....
            
            
         .. the same to this.entitieSearchMachinesDataSource = entitiesSearch;
                        this.entitieSearchApplicatifsDataSource = entitiesSearch;

    //HOWTO RETURN.....???
  }


  public getQuickSearchData<T>(quicksearch:Quicksearch,query:string, Lst_stc: string, with_orphan: number): Observable<T[]>{
    return this.apiHttpService
    .get(this.apiAccueilService.getQuickSearch(quicksearch,query,Lst_stc,with_orphan))
    .pipe(
           catchError(this.apiHttpService.handleError),
           map((entitiesSearch:T[]) => {
              return entitiesSearch.length>=1 ? entitiesSearch : [];
          }),
    );
  }
```

Howto retrieve in getQuickSearch the value of the 4 datasource?

Comment: Are these `this.entiteSearchService.entitieSearchActifsDataSource` http request in the question? Does it send the data and you save it `this.entitieSearchActifsDataSource` ?

Comment: Hello Apoorva, thanks for reply. My entiteSearchService.getQuickSearch  need to call 4 http and foreach call I set the datasource of each one in a property  entitieSearchActifsDataSource, entitieSearchApplicatifsDataSource and so  on, and In my component when I subscribe the getQuickSearch and the the operation is complete I retrieve the 4 datasource like that entiteSearchService.entitieSearchActifsDataSource and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not subscribe in your service.
Instead, create your 4 Observables, and then combine the Observables to manage the results. Like here :

https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs

```js
let character = this.http.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/1');
    let characterHomeworld = this.http.get('http://swapi.co/api/planets/1');
```

To consume the Observables :

```js
    forkJoin([character, characterHomeworld]).subscribe(results => {
      // results[0] is our character
      // results[1] is our character homeworld
      results[0].homeworld = results[1];
      this.loadedCharacter = results[0];
    });
```

You have other operators to combine streams, like combineLatest :
https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest

Comment: Hello Alain, thanks for the reply, I was hill, and I can´t not reply soon. I agree with your solution, I will implement it like you said.

Comment: Hello ! I'm glad you find this helpfull, rxjs operators can be tricky but they really help make the code clean ! Cheers !